# ThreeCSG expand gives faulty mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, csg

I'm trying to create a rounded cube using the ThreeCSG expand function on a csg model, but the resulting mesh looks wrong. I can't figure out what the problem is though. Does anyone have experience with ThreeCSG and see what's up ? thanks. the code:

```
var a = CSG.cube();
var b = a.expand( 0.4, 6 ); 
this.m_scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( THREE.CSG.fromCSG( b ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() ) );
```

the resulting mesh is here:

[image: mesh]
<sub>(source: [jvanderspek.com](http://www.jvanderspek.com/dev/AutoKAT/csgerror.png))</sub>

thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Your **vertexNormals** somehow fail. Seems they got "lost in translation".

Check [my answer on another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959721/1697459). 
It might be the same problem.